# How do I assign Keyboard Shortcuts?

Tags: shortcut, keymap

I would say about only 50% of my keyboard shortcuts are working.  I'm on a Mac running 10.13.6.  I can't seem to find the version of Blender I am using, but I've downloaded it within the last month.  I can't find anywhere in preferences to assigned hotkeys.  Any suggestions?

Bill Shortridge
Sebastopol, CA

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 2):

If you click on the Blender logo in the menu bar, to the right of the *File* menu and select *Splash Screen*, it will tell you the version in the splash screen.

[image: How to find splash screen]

It should also tell you the version in the lower left corner of the Blender window. If it's not visible, right click there and enable *Blender Version* in the popup.

[image: How to show splashscreen in the footer]

Keyboard shortcuts are under [keymap](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/editors/preferences/keymap.html) in the preferences.

[image: Preferences showing keymap]

To set a shortcut, search for the command by name in the search bar, find the command in the list, and select an existing shortcut to replace.  Click on the shortcut and key in the replacement.

It's also possible to change short cuts using the right mouse menu:

- hover over a menu entry or other item that can have a shortcut.
- right click
- select *Assign Shortcut*

[image: right click to bring up shortcut setting tools]

Answer (score 1):

As a Mac user i used this:

[image]

Go to preferences (shortcut: <kbd>COMMAND</kbd> <kbd>,</kbd> while the cursor is in the 3d viewport), click on input and check

- emulate numpad (if you don't have one)
- emulate 3 button mouse (if you don't have one)

This should solve some shortcut problems which includes numbers.

If you still have problems you can search in keymap for other shortcuts and change them as you like.

If still a shortcut does not work, let us know.

It would be good if you would have given us an example which specific shortcut won't work for you so we could give you a more specific help.